# can't pas values to a angular observable

Tags: angular, observable

i am trying to use a observable to see if the user data is changed and if so i want to update the router.but the problem is every time i update the user the subscription is not activated its only activated on initialization.

i get the user from auth0 subscription and then pas it on to the currentUser

userservice.ts

```
private currentUser: userDto = {}
public currentUserObserv: Observable<userDto> = of(this.currentUser)
```

routingService.ts

```
  private userSubscription = this.userService.currentUserObserv.subscribe(
user => this.handleRoles(user)
```

)

Answer (score 1):

`of()` creates a cold observable that does nothing.

What you want is a `BehaviorSubject`.

```js
private _currentUser = new BehaviorSubject<userDto>({});
public currentUser$ = this._currentUser.asObservable();
get currentUser() { return this._currentUser.value; }
setCurrentUser(user: userDto) { this._currentUser.next(user); }
```

Comment: yes thank you a lot this works but what is the diffrence between an observable and behaviorsubject

Comment: An observable can be observed with `subscribe`, creating an observer. A subject (Subject, BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject) is both an observable and an observer : you can observe it, and you can control it (send values into it to trigger the observers).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) or [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) (which keeps the current value) for this purpose.

```
private currentUserSubject: Subject<userDto> = new Subject<userDto>();
public currentUser$: Observable<userDto> = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    
emitNewUser(user: userDto): void {
  this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
}
```